Can't implement playwright in behave steps file
So In steps file I wrote this code and it just stops. Nothing really happens. It opens and closes down in seconds, I can't understand why?
Error: raise Error("Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?")
   playwright._impl._errors.Error: Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?

  When the user enters a valid username.        # None
  And the user logs out from the application.     # None

What I tried:
from behave import *
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

# Initialize playwright outside step definitions
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=800)
    page = browser.new_page()


@given(u'the user is on Pilot server login page.')
def step_impl(context):
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")


@when(u'the user enters a valid username.')
def step_impl(context):
    button_by_role = page.get_by_role('link', name="Docs")
    button_by_role.click()


@when(u'the user logs out from the application.')
def step_impl(context):
    page.screenshot(path="features/Screenshots/demo.png")  # Taking screenshot for the proof


When the with block ends, Playwright is closed. So the tests need to be inside of the with, or use Playwright without with.

Does this answer your question? can i run playwright outside of 'with'?
